# Connecting my Wii Balance Board to my Wii U?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

Does Wii Fit, played on a Wii U, support the Wii Balance Board? I tried to sync it, but nothing happened.

I mean 'nothing happened' as in, I pressed both Sync buttons, and the light from the Balance Board flashed, but the screen didn't advance and it stopped flashing after a while. I presume nothing happened.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade. Please describe what you have tried until now a bit more in detail, and what you mean by 'nothing happened'

Comment: There is no Wii U specific version of the Balance Board, so it should work.

Comment: Here, I added a bit more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try opening up the Home Menu, then select "Controller settings".
Go to "Wii Remote/Other Controllers" and then tap "Pair".
Then press the sync button on the Balance Board.

Comment: One small addition. In case you already have 4 normal controllers added and active you need to wait for one of them to power off before you can sync the balance board.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting up the game then when it asks you about your balance board (if you have it connected) press the sync button or the middle button on the board.

Answer (score 0):

I pressed sync on the Wii-u. The Wii-u then prompted to press sync on the "remote". Pressed sync on the board (twice, once to wake up and second to start sync). Board light started flashing and after about a minute, the Wii-u said complete. Tested successfully with Wii fit. PS, there's a Wii-u balance board that comes with a different Wii-u Fit game.